# Webscraping with Selenium using Xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I'm looking for some numbers on https://tnnslive.com/

The numbers I'm looking for on tnnslive.com:

[image: the numbers I'm looking for on tnnslive.com]

If I copy the xpath in Chrome, I get:

```
//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[7]/div/div[2]
```

If I run the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Start a new Chrome browser session
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER")

# Navigate to the desired URL
driver.get('https://tnnslive.com/match/VDDGj17PodORnq62YwQk')

# Find the element by its XPath and print its text
element = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[7]/div/div[2]')    

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

the error occurs:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[7]/div/div[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=115.0.5790.171)
```

Why? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the text associated with ***1st Serve Points Won*** for the first player within the [website](https://tnnslive.com/match/MpVVddDZigie7GHM9ip8) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*, *`following-sibling`* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get(url='https://tnnslive.com/match/MpVVddDZigie7GHM9ip8')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='1st Serve Points Won']//following-sibling::div[1]"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*, *`following`* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.get(url='https://tnnslive.com/match/MpVVddDZigie7GHM9ip8')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='1st Serve Points Won']//following::div[1]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  64% (29/45)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902072/7429447)

Comment: It is better to use just one slash instead of two slashes `//` before `following`